# Unfamiliar syntax for initializing an array/struct, looking for explanation

Tags: c, syntax, c99, c11, aggregate-initialization

I'm looking through the "Processor Modeling Guide" provided by a company named OVP (a product similar to qemu).  In it, there's a little code snippet resembling the following:

```
static or1kDispatchTableC dispatchTable = {
  // handle arithmetic instructions
  [OR1K_IT_ADDI] = disDefault,
  [OR1K_IT_ADDIC] = disDefault,
  [OR1K_IT_ANDI] = disDefault,
  [OR1K_IT_ORI] = disDefault,
  [OR1K_IT_XORI] = disDefault,
  [OR1K_IT_MULI] = disDefault
};
```

I've never seen syntax like this before.  *irrelevant stuff about C++ removed*

At the moment I don't have the ability to download/look at their stuff to look at how anything is defined, hence my question.  If you recognize this syntax, can you weigh in?

---

*edit*

`or1kDispatchTableC` is a typedef for a pointer of type `or1kDispatchTableCP`, but I still don't have anything on what `or1kDispatchTableCP` is.

Comment: Either C++ has changed more than I thought in the last few years (highly likely) or somebody's doing some strange redefining of the [] operator.  I'd start digging in to the constructor/assignment operator definition of that or1kDispatchTableC, then figure out what that thing is it's trying to take.  But no, never seen that before.

Comment: Probably going to have to wait 'til I can get access to their headers to get the full answer.

Comment: the [] operator for what? there is no left hand side..

Comment: If this ( http://www.ovpworld.org/documents/OVP_Processor_Modeling_Guide.pdf ) is anything to go by, or1kDispatchTableC is an array of function pointers, and OR1K_IT_* are all enum tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, assuming your first line is a typo, or `or1kDispatchTableC` is an array type, so that this is actually an array declaration, this looks like a C11 explicitly initialized array.  The line

```
[OR1K_IT_ADDI] = disDefault,
```

initializes element `OR1K_IT_ADDI` to `disDefault`.  Both of those need to be constant expressions -- `OR1K_IT_ADDI` is probably a #define or an enum tag.

I'm pretty sure that C++11  does NOT support this syntax, though some compilers (that also support C11) might support it as an extension.

From the names, I would guess that this is actually an array of function pointers.

Comment: The "C11" in here may look to some like that is only supported starting from C11. But designated initializers have been valid starting from C99.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly it.  For reference, here's the GCC documentation on it: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html

Answer (score 2):

This is called *designated initializers* and is a C feature (supported since C99). It allows addressing array and structure/union elements directly, filling the gaps with default values.

```
struct foo { int a[10]; };
struct foo f[] = { [5].a[3] = 20 };
```

Now this results in `5` elements of `struct foo`, all initialized to zero followed by a sixth element of `struct foo` with the 4th element of `a` initialized to 20.

Like someone else suspected, this is not supported by C++.

Comment: Thank you for the example, and you're absolutely right; it's not even implemented as an extension for g++.